# How to make the clickable area larger without impacting other elements?

Tags: html, css

I want an inline element to be easier to click. I can add padding, but I don't want to impact other elements. I can undo that with negative margin, but it leads to odd results:

```css
span {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: -5px;

  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
ab<span>c</span>def
```

If you try to hover over it, the pointer does not show up in the whole red area but goes away to the right of the `c` (where the `d` is). An `onClick` callback would work the same. Why does this happen, and how do I prevent it?

Comment: I'm super curious why you don't want a whole word/phrase/etc. to be the hyperlink. What is the full use case here? This doesn't seem like a really discoverable/usable scenario if the full word/words are not linked.

Comment: I don't know the technical reason why it behaves like that, but you can fix your issue by adding `position: relative` to the span.

Comment: After adding negative margin, it will reduce the area of span and your curser will only point till span area thats why its not coming over the d.

Comment: Also adding position:relative will push the d word behind the red area which is not good.

Comment: @Leothelion I don't understand the general rule based on this. `d` being behind the red seems good - I won't actually be using the red background, it's just to illustrate the clickable area.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to add an anchor tag around both your inline element and some surrounding elements as well.

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  alert('clicked')
})
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 3em;
}
span {
  background: pink;
}
a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background: lime;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover>span {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
a<a>b<span>c</span>d</a>ef
```

Otherwise you could dynamically insert an absolutely-positioned element to be your click target.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.s1').forEach(sc => {
  const s = '<span class="s2"></span>'
  sc.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', s)
})
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains('s2')) alert('clicked')
})
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 3em;
}
.s1 {
  position: relative;
}
.s2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1rem;
  right: -1rem;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: pink;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.s2:hover {
  background-color: lime;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
ab<span class="s1">c</span>def
```

Comment: I'm generating these dynamically in a complicated way, the "`d`" might in fact be in a different subtree, so this doesn't work. I don't think I want it all be clickable either, it's just that the `d` is covering up some of the intended clickable area.

Comment: Please describe your "intended clickable area"

Comment: the example in my OP uses `background-color: red` to highlight it

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide a second solution.

Comment: seems to work, thanks. Not accepting because a comment under OP pointed out adding `position: relative` works, which seems like a better solution if we just want a solution. I'm still looking for an explanation of how this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS class that'll define a *pseudo element* `::before` which expands the clickable area without affecting the layout:

```css
.clickable {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    left: -5px;
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
    position: absolute;
  }
  &:hover {
    background: orange;
  }  
}
```

```html
ab<span class="clickable" onclick="console.log('clicked')">c</span>def
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this.

Imagine you have a text with several clickable words. And know imagine they are neighbours, vertically and/or horizontally.
The clickable areas will overlap each other.

This will not end good for UXP.

Comment: This should be comment rather then answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the clickable area by adding before and after pseudo elements to the span.

This snippet adds a 5px transparent clickable area before and after. That way the adjacent characters are not disturbed, and it is clear which character is clickable.

```css
span {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

span::before {
  margin-left: -5px;
}
```

```html
ab<span>c</span>def
```